# How do I resolve the NoSuchElementException error in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53onI.jpg)I was following an online tutorial on scraping glassdoor website via selenium.
My code does not get through this statement:

```
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("selected").click()
        print('x out worked')
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        print('x out failed')
        pass

    time.sleep(.1)

    try:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[alt="Close"]').click()
        print(' x out worked')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print(' x out failed (next page or missing)')
        pass
```

The error I receive is :

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".selected"}

Couple of things that I tried:

1. driver.maximize_window()
2. driver.implicitly_wait(20)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing the HTML, but try reversing your quotes (single/double)...

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[alt='Close']").click()
```

Or...

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@alt='Close']")
```

If that doesn't work add the relevant HTML section to your post

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My code does not run even on the first try catch clause:
try:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("selected").click()
        print('x out worked')
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        print('x out failed')
        pass

I have added the screenshot of my html in the beginning of the post.

Comment: It is very difficult to tell from that screenshot what element you are trying to target.  Can you highlight the exact element in the HTML and re-post that instead?

Comment: Edited. I am trying to click the first job on the page.

Comment: Try this:  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//article[@id='MainCol']/li[1]")

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. I had double quotation on id = "MainCol" instead of id = 'MainCol'.

Comment: Ok, if for some reason it doesn't work try this instead:  //article[@id='MainCol']/div[1]/ul/li[1].  I just logged into Glassdoor and tried it so I know it works :). If you want to loop through all the jobs you could set the <li> value as a parameter and increment through it

Comment: That sounds very interesting. You mean increment <li> as in 1,2,3 .....?

Comment: Yep. You can wrap it in a loop, and change the value in li to a variable (so li[1], li[2]...) etc if you want to click on all of them on the page